# NodeLoad module gives Error : Object #<Client> has no method 'destroy'

Tags: node.js, request, nodeload

I am using NodeLoad module of nodejs for sending multiple request at same time for testing server node app, but if i use `numUsers : 50` than it's work perfectly for me. When I take `numUsers : 300` than Gives me Error Like : `TypeError: Object #<Client> has no method 'destroy'`

NodeLoad App I used

```
timeLimit: 10,
targetRps: 5,
numUsers : 300,
```

Error :

```
},reconnect=function(){var oldclient=client;if(oldclient){oldclient.destroy();
                                                                ^
TypeError: Object #<Client> has no method 'destroy'
at reconnect (/root/nodeLoadDemo/nodeload/node_modules/nodeload/nodeload.js:9:506)
at Client.<anonymous> (/root/nodeLoadDemo/nodeload/node_modules/nodeload/nodeload.js:10:180)
at Client.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (http.js:2144:10)
at ClientRequest.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
at Socket.socketOnEnd [as onend] (http.js:1568:9)
at Socket.g (events.js:180:16)
at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
at _stream_readable.js:919:16
at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
```

So, can any one Explain me How Error  ? And Solution for these Error ?

Thank you .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an Answer

[Click Here To go on Solution](https://github.com/benschmaus/nodeload/pull/16/files)

You Just need to change in `node modules`. open `nodeload` modules and nodeload.js file check line 9 at end of sentence `replace`

`if (oldclient) { oldclient.destroy(); }`

**TO**

`if (oldclient && oldclient.destroy) { oldclient.destroy(); }`